# Confused by behaviour of my python code involving loops and files

Tags: python

I want to begin by thanking all those who are always there trying to help one.
Then I also want to apologize for the language as English is not my main language!

I wonder what's wrong I've done since I can not use my script.

I had hoped that it would move to the next text file ('q2.txt') from text file one ('q1.txt').

But it does not. Without it stays on I or E may depend on answering the questions.

The questions are divided into a text file and separated by ";"
First is the questions, then A and B

Hope I managed to explain my problem.
Thanks for all your help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# name.py



def questions(fileName):
    fileName = open(fileName, 'r')
    counter_a, counter_b = 0, 0
    for questions in fileName:
        lineSplit = questions.split(','); # for every new line, split separtes whit "," for one quastion and      two choides
        question_string = "%s\n %s\n %s\n \n Answer: " % (lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1], lineSplit[2])
        answer = raw_input(question_string).lower()
        while answer not in ("a", "b"):
            print("Please choose A or B \n")
            answer = raw_input(question_string).lower()
    if answer == "a":
        counter_a += 1
    else:
        counter_b += 1

#print "A total is %d" % counter_a
#print "B total is %d" % counter_b


    if counter_a > counter_b:
        print 'Your first personality code is: E'
    else:
        print 'Your first personality code is: I'

def main():
    questions('q1.txt')
    questions('q2.txt')

if __name__=='__main__': main()
```

--

Hello,

Thanks for all the responses I received. I'll try to explain.

The script retrieves questions from the specified text file. These are divided by "," in the text file per line.
example of a question and answer appears in the text file: At a party do you interact with many person?, A: Including strangers, B: Interact with a few known to you

Each time you choose A or B, you get a "score" for A+1 or B+1.

Once all questions are answered, you get based on how you answered a letter. This works great. There is no problem in the script to perform this task.

The problem is that it does not go further in the function, it will not go over to the text file number two!

That is, from q1.txt to q2.txt.
     questions ('q1.txt')
     questions ('q2.txt')

It stops after get the answer.
Your first personality code is: E
or
Your first personality code is: I

I hope this was a better explanation of what I'm after. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: "q1.txt" exampel: At a party do you interact with many persons?, A: Including strangers, B: Interact with a few known to you

Comment: "I wonder what's wrong I've done since I can not use my script". Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? Is it running, but not printing the expected output? If so, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: Really can't get what you are trying to do. What do you mean when you say it should move from `q1.txt` to `q2.txt`?

Comment: @RohitJain Analysing the code, I'm fairly certain that he's misdiagnosing the problem.

Comment: Please show example file input, and an example interactive session. This is a minimum for all questions.

Answer (score 0):

This line is *a* problem with your code, although without example input and output it is difficult to diagnose *the* problem:

```
for questions in fileName:
```

This line reads a single byte from `fileName` per iteration, and places it in `questions`. What you almost certainly want is to read the file line-by-line. Consult the python documentation on files and streams to learn how to do that (I'm not going to do your homework for you).

Now, the next thing that happens is this:

```
    answer = raw_input(question_string).lower()
    while answer not in ("a", "b"):
        print("Please choose A or B \n")
        answer = raw_input(question_string).lower()
```

But, you don't do anything with `answer` once you have it. You just return to the top of the for loop. Once you use up all the bytes in `fileName`, and exit the loop, you hit:

```
if answer == "a":
    counter_a += 1
else:
    counter_b += 1

if counter_a > counter_b:
    print 'Your first personality code is: E'
else:
    print 'Your first personality code is: I'
```

And then you exit the function. Accordingly, the final print out is determined by the last value entered for `answer`.

What you probably want is to move the first `if` statement inside the `for` loop. Remember: indentation in Python is *not* optional.